# Configure disaster recovery and automatic failover for Azure SQL Database?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, disaster-recovery

We have our Azure Sql database provisioned in East US and our hot-stand by region is West US.

I know that Azure Sql database supports Geo-Replication and failover groups.

How do I configure the Azure Sql database to support the disaster recovery with automatic failover? Would it impact the connection string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use read-write listener for OLTP workload: When performing OLTP operations, use "failover-group-name.database.windows.net" as the server URL and the connections are automatically directed to the primary. This URL does not change after the failover. Note the failover involves updating the DNS record so the client connections are redirected to the new primary only after the client DNS cache is refreshed. Read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/auto-failover-group-overview?tabs=azure-powershell) for more details.

Comment: Can you please repost the reference link?

Comment: I don't know why is blocked. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/auto-failover-group-overview?tabs=azure-powershell

Comment: The DNS record update is automatic. Is managed by Azure

Comment: On the reference link you will be able to read this: "After the database failover is completed, the DNS record is automatically updated to redirect the endpoints to the new region"